# My first time with React project- currency converter, multiple axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, axios

I'm trying to conver my currency app into a React and a hit a wall. Idk how to inplement axios into React, idk if i can show all my code but i will try. I tried go with a class component and this.state, but it might be a dead end. I dont wonna put my js app, so i link codepen.

https://codepen.io/marcin-panasiuk/pen/rNWQLrw

This is my misereble try in React:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './Przelicznik.css';

const Currencies = () => {
    const Fetch = () => {
        const one = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/CHF/";
        const two = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/EUR/";
        const three = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/USD/";

        const requestOne = axios.get(one);
        const requestTwo = axios.get(two);
        const requestThree = axios.get(three);

        axios
            .all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
            for (var i of responses){
            let newArr = responses.map((i) => ({code:i.data.code, value: i.data.rates[0].mid}))
            button.addEventListener('click', (e) => calculate(newArr));
            }
        }))
            .catch(errors => {
            console.log(errors);
         });

         const Calculate = () => {
            if (input.value == "") {
                alert("Wpisz kwotę")
              } else {
                let res = currArr.filter(i => i.code == selector.value)[0].value;
                let result = input.value * res;
                result = result.toFixed(2);
                endresult.textContent = result + "zł"
              }    
            }
            
         }
         return (
           
            <div class="container-przel">
                <input className="input" placeholder="0" value={1}/>
                <select className="currencies">
                    <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
                    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                     <option value="USD">USD</option>
                </select>
    
                <button className="button" type="button" onclick={e => calculate()}>Przelicz!</button>
                <p className="endresult"></p>
            </div>
            
    
  );
}
export default Waluta;
```

How to properly implement axios and all functions inside React.

Comment: I would suggest using a data-fetching library such as SWR or react-query to save you plenty of pain...

Comment: Additionally, since the http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/A/CHF/ API does not support CORS, you will not be able to get the data from another origin anyway.

Comment: I have a question, im totally newbie in js and react is totally new for me. Where i can check that the api have a CORS data?

Comment: You can look at the response headers for the API endpoint in your browser dev tools or use an online tester such as https://myxml.in/cors-tester.html (freshly googled, didn't try).